# Mongo Query That Doesn't Display Duplicates From A Sort And Only Shows Certain Fields

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm working on a query that sorts my data in the order of greatest to least (altitude). My results must display only the "aircraft_id" and the "altitude". Also, when my list is sorted, the first few hundred entries are all duplicates recorded at slightly different times. So I need to exclude duplicates containing the same altitude and aircraft_id. Currently I have as follows...

```
db.planes.aggregate([{$match: 
{altitude: {$ne: ""}}},
{$sort: {altitude: -1}}],
{allowedDiskUse: true})
```

I'm not sure if this questions makes any sense, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: We have query, but we don't have sample of data which you are querying. Please update question with sample documents and sample result which you are trying to get

Answer (score 0):

To get only unique aricraft_id and altitude pairs you can group documents by aircraft_id with adding unique altitudes to set (with `$addToSet` operation). After that unwind groups to get unique pairs.

Use `$project` stage to select only fields which you want:

```
db.planes.aggregate([
   {$match: {altitude: {$ne: ""}}},
   {$group: {_id: "$aircraft_id", altitude: {$addToSet: "$altitude"}}},
   {$unwind: "$altitude"},
   {$project: {"aircraft_id": "$_id", "altitude": 1 }},
   {$sort: {altitude: -1 }}
],
{allowedDiskUse: true})
```

Comment: When I run that query, nothing happens and mongo seems to be expecting more code written. When I press enter it moves to a new line and prints "...". If I hit enter twice more, it reverts back to a awaiting a new command.

Comment: @sixshotsix there was one missing curly brace in $group stage. Btw have seen my comment under the question?